# Journey - using updated data from Contact picks wrong info

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, wait-element

I have a journey, where multiple contacts with same Subscriber Key enter the journey.

Example: One customer can have multiple Orders. Each Order is a separate record in the Journey. At the pickup time, push notification is sent to customer. But the pickup time might change.

In above example, if I use pickup time from Contact, it picks the most recent pickup date from Contact, and sends all the notifications for all orders, at a single datetime.

Also the Journey mentions the same thing. Is there any work-around to use the pickup datetime of the respective order, and not the most updated value?

[image]